# PAM authenticates or requests authentication?

Tags: login, password, authentication, pam

Can PAM be used to request authentication (make sure the user has a password without access to password itself) or to authenticate on behalf of the user (to implement alternative authentication)?

I would like to implement passing login screen with a USB stick and am looking for a framework that will let me order the system to pass the login screen when something else happened, like a USB stick was detected.

Comment: Some program requests authentication, PAM does authentication for that app. So, you could write a PAM module that does USB-key based authentication (for example, that's how [fingerprint  authentication](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui/) works on Ubuntu). But it would still require the login screen to make a PAM request, and I don't know if that can be done on simply plugging in a USB stick.

Comment: Can I use `python-pam` to implement a program that authenticates when a USB stick got plugged in?